# Display data that no model exists in a serializer - Python - Django - Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-rest-viewsets

I have a "Model-Viewset-Serializer" and I need my Serializer to display additional fields that don't exist in the model.

**Model:**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, null=False)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
```

**Viewset:**

```py
class MyViewSet(
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet
):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(organization_id=request.user.my_connection_id)
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        serializer = MySerializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

**Serializer:**

```py
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('id', 'type', 'name', 'description', 'array')
```

*I need to add the following object to the preview*

**array:**

```json
[
    {'status': 'ok', 'value': '1'},
    {'status': 'pending', 'value': '5'},
    {'status': 'approval', 'value': '3'},
    {'status': 'rejected', 'value': '4'}
]
```

**description:** 'text description'

Comment: On which endpoint do you want this additional fields, and how do you build it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create raw properties in your `Serializer` suppose that you have that data array in some part of you code where `data` is the value you want to add to your `Serializer`:

```
data = [
    {'status': 'ok', 'value': '1'},
    {'status': 'pending', 'value': '5'},
    {'status': 'approval', 'value': '3'},
    {'status': 'rejected', 'value': '4'}
]
```

Then you can add the following property to your serializer `MySerializer` and it will look like this:

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    array = serializers.ReadOnlyField(default=data)
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('id', 'type', 'name', 'description', 'array')
```

Where array is custom property of your serializer, `ReadOnlyField` is used in different ways like displaying related info instead of the pk in a relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You can create additional fields in your serializer with using `SerializerMethodField`.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield